# Hide removable device from explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

I want to make my USB stick 'inaccessible' for dummy users.   So, is there any way to hide removable device from Explorer using registry or an util (which doesn't require new driver)?

Comment: For good, or evil?

Comment: For good, to keep my stick unaccesible for evil dummies =)

Answer (score 2):

You can hide drives in WinXP&Vista using microsoft's discontinued shared computer toolkit "steady state". (Easiest way but only runs on 32bit Pre Win7 OS)

I also know it can be done via group policy.

Look Under User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Explorer
 You can hide drives there. If this machine is not on a domain, use local policy.

Comment: OK. Can you clarify your answer and tell us more ?)

Comment: Years ago microsoft had this tool for shared computers (computer labs, libraries, kiosks, etc...) it was called steady state. (Check C-Net) One of the features it had was the ability to lock down a local account pretty extensivly and one of the options was to hide drives ONLY from the account you're locking down. We used it to hide C:\ from the kids in the lab so they couldn't snoop around. It MAY work for your needs, but it only runs in 32-bit OS. I know it runs in XP and Vista only. Rumor has it that it'll run in 7 if you trick the installer by running the setup in compatability mode.

Comment: When Win7 came out, Microsoft stopped supporting Steady State, but you can still find it around. What you want to do CAN be done by group policy though, check out "Hide these specified drives in My Computer" User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Explorer

Comment: Thanks for great info. It helped me. But is there a way to hide it without administrative privileges (with or without tools)? I'd like "auto-hide" it (probably by using autorun.inf), when I plug it to a PC.

Comment: don't hold your breath on that. Most good tricks need admin rights.