# Hiding usb drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

Is there any way to hide an usb drive STRAIGHT after you plug it in? Without the windows telling you there's new drive attached, but:

1. Without modifying the registry
2. Without touching device manager

I want to achieve that when I plugin a pendrive with letter X for example, I must be the only one knowing that going to letter X through file explorer (writing the path X: or in cmd X:) I can get my files.

Cant this be done with the autorun.inf ?

Comment: So someone opens Explorer and sees `MYSECRETTHUMB (X:)`. Now what?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Is there any way to hide an usb drive STRAIGHT after you plug it in? this is the main question :P

Comment: You do write in the question that what you want to achieve is that "I must be the only one knowing that going to letter X through file explorer I can get my files".

Comment: this may help [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BSD5eQnb4A)

Comment: You can not make it through autorun.inf.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ima get straight, the i want to hide an drive once you plug it in the usb port, so it can be only accesed by its letter...

Comment: Simply tape both data pins and it will be completely hidden! You cannot hide the “Installing device” message, you also can’t change what Device Manager or Disk Management displays. Security through obscurity is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question has been answered here:
[Hide removable device from explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/553800/hide-removable-device-from-explorer)

However, if this is not the case let us know